# Same jQuery code writes different JSON data on local and online server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm writing a jQuery app that reads and writes a JSON file containing HTML. When executing the code shown below on my local Ubuntu test server everything works as expected.  When executing identical code on my ISPs on-line server it behaves differently (and fails).  Both web servers are Apache and the jQuery components are loaded from googleapis in both cases.

The problem is with escaping embedded double-quotes in the HTML saved in JSON.  The escaping happens automatically when I write the file on the local server, like this:

```
<span class=\"heading\">
```

but after writing the file on the online server, it's like this:

```
<span class="heading">.
```

Since each JSON item is itself enclosed in " it looks as if the inner quotes cause an error next time the file is read.

Full JSON file before execution:

```
{"userItem":["<li><span class=\"heading\"><span class=\"handle\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span></span>Heading 1</span></li>","<li><span class=\"item\"><span class=\"handle\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span></span>Action 1</span></li>"]}
```

The JSON file written after execution on the **local** server is identical. All the cut down code from the app shown below does is load the file, display contents and save the file after pressing the "Save your work" button.

The JSON data after execution on the **online** server is like this:

```
{"userItem":["<li><span class="heading"><span class="handle"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span></span>Heading 1</span></li>","<li><span class="item"><span class="handle"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span></span>Action 1</span></li>"]}
```

If I run this online, press the "Save your work" button, then refresh the page, I see my console.log error message:
JSON file invalid or not found

I'm guessing this is a web server setting, PHP setting or JSON version (??) but have no idea how to overcome it.  I tried using " to enclose JSON items, and ' to enclose 'heading', 'handle', etc.  And I tried reversing the use of ' and ", but the JSON is written out using " in all cases.

I should add that I have $json = stripslashes($json); in the PHP because without it I get multiple \ escaping of all " with three backslashes.

Can anyone see something I'm doing wrong, please?

PHP on the local server is PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6
PHP on the online server is PHP Version 5.3.28

If it's a PHP version issue, any suggestions for overcoming it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
// Function to  READ  existing data from JSON file
            // Assign handlers immediately after making the request
            // and load data to HTML
            function loadData() {
                $.getJSON('todo.json',function(data){
                    console.log('success');
                    $.each(data.userItem,function(i,item){
                        $('.list').append(item);
                    });
                }).error(function(){
                    console.log('JSON file invalid or not found');
                });
            }

// Function to  WRITE  data to JSON file
            function writeData() {
                var jsonObject = { "userItem" : [] };
                var allUserItems = $("li"); 
                    for ( var index = 0; index < allUserItems.length; index++) {
                    jsonObject.userItem[index] = allUserItems[index].outerHTML;
                };
                // some jQuery to write to file
                $.ajax( {
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "todojson.php",
                    data : { json : JSON.stringify(jsonObject) },
                    success: function () {console.log("Good!"); },
                    error: function() {console.log("Error!");}
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                loadData (); // get and display JSON data from past sessions

                // SAVE contents of page to json file when 'Save your work' button pressed
                $('#buttonSave').click(function () { // code for the blue Save button
                    $( this ).animate({ color: "#00ff00" }, 300 );
                    writeData();
                    $( this ).animate({ color: "#fff" }, 500 );
                });
            });

        </script>

        <title>Action list</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="controls" style="width: 100%">
            <div id="buttonSave"> Save your work </div>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <ul class="list">
            <!-- HTML from JSON file loaded here -->
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP that writes the JSON is:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['json'];
$json = stripslashes($json);

$file = fopen('todo.json','w+');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Well, `$json = stripslashes($json);` is the problem. You shouldn't need it. If there are three backslashes before a quote, it just means that this particular quote was escaped in the original data. Not *all* quotes were. Get rid of them in only in the part where they are.

Comment: Thanks, but no, they weren't escaped in the original data.  Was mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rely on magic_quotes_gpc being on:

```
$json = stripslashes($json);
```

Make it:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $json = stripslashes($json);
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick!  Thanks.  Will try, and report back.

Comment: Magic! That did the trick - works on both servers now.  I have to wait 5 minutes to flag it as accepted apparently, but will do so.